# Exclude posts from postlist

Tags: php, wordpress, post, slider

I have a post list on my homepage that is displaying all posts in chronological order (DESC). I want to exclude posts from a specific category from this list. How do I go about this? My query is...

```
<ul class="home-news"><?php
                        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
                        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
                        foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
                            <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                                <span>Posted on <?php the_date(); ?></span>  
                            </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Add the following to your `args` array:

```
$args = array( 'category' => '-id', ...);
```

Where `id` is the category id of the category you want to exclude. This solution will not diminish the number of posts requested.

**Solution 2**

Add the following at the beginning of the inside of the `foreach` loop:

```
<?php 
    $category = get_the_category();
    if ($category[0] -> cat_name == 'exclude_category_name') continue;
 ?>
```

Note that if posts have multiple categories, you'd want to loop through the `$category` array and check each element.

Comment: This just seems to exclude the posts from 'Events' from the 5 posts that were initially called. I'd like the excluded posts to be replaced in the list with older posts from eligible categories.

Comment: Since your `$postlist` is constructed from the `get_posts()` function call, it's not going to be possible to add new entries to `$postlist` with the code you have here. You'll have to change how `get_posts()` works

Comment: Cheers, I've managed to get the query working to my requirements by using the following code [link](http://justpaste.it/o0y)

Comment: @Kelvin see my update. This option is also available with get_posts(), per this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-category-from-get_posts